# Show when the bounty is ending in the Featured list

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bountied-tab

When we go to a page like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=featured we see the active Bounties on a certain tag (in this case, Python).

When we put the cursor on the blue bounty box in the list we can see the message

> this question has an open bounty worth XX reputation
>
> [image]

Wouldn't it be useful to have the end time of the bounty so that it shows... ?

> this question has an open bounty worth XX reputation *ending in YY days*

Comment: I might add that this was [briefly accidentally implemented due to a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332036/remove-the-end-time-of-bounties-from-question-titles), but it was reverted following a request.

Answer (score 2):

Great idea!

I would even be for a system where the color of the blue bounty indicator changes from dark blue to light blue throughout its life cycle.

Dark blue on first offering, light blue when it's about to expire.

Comment: Good one, this blue variation would help to have a good overview about which bounties are about to expire!