# Remove the end time of bounties from question titles?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design, bounties

So today I chimed in on IPS and scrolled a bit. This question caught my eye, because it had a number in it.

[image]

Something like that I haven't seen in a long time, if ever. Then I read the title and was confused at first, because it started with

> ends in 4 days How do I...

This is obviously not proper English. It took me some time to realize that the text size isn't even the same, because the difference is very little in my opinion.

Also, I don't see any reason why that text is necessary in the title.

- It gives no additional incentive to answer the question
- It seems like it's part of the question title
- It's already obvious that the question has a bounty
- The time until a bounty runs out is already visible inside a question

This update looks better or worse depending on the site style, but overall I think that it's not something that is needed and has more drawback than it adds.

So I am wondering why this text has been added in the first place and if it can be removed again? Perhaps a per-site solution is possible. I am open to discussion about it (mostly interested in what that text adds to the user experience).

Comment: Related/duplicate: [New bounty design dislocates title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332030/295232) - I proposed to move the bounty information to the right to make sure it isn't interpreted as part of the question title.

Comment: @rene could you switch aroind the duplicate, this answer is more usefull then the answer on the other Q.

Comment: @Luuklag meh, let's be done with it. I have better things to do., besides, the other has an answer that links back to this one so nothing is going to be lost. If anything, consider a merge. Then you have only one q/a pair with the best answers in one spit. No need for the dupes at all.

Comment: @rene sounds fair, modflagged this one.

Comment: This makes no sense. I originally dupflagged the other question, and recieved the comment "@pppery this question was asked first, it was posted two hours earlier, it also has two answers." and the close-vote review queue being finalized as "leave open". I thus assumed that the leave open reviews were due to people thinking the duplicate should be the other way around, and dupflagged this one.

Comment: @pppery yeah, it is not you, you're fine. It is just a bunch of reviewers that got the stuff mixed up. We spend so much time and votes on these two questions, you start to wonder if there are no other questions left that need close votes ....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is fixed.

I was removing some dead code from the codebase, and accidentally changed some code from `if (false && b && c)` to `if (b && c)` instead or removing it entirely.

### Full context:

We show a UI very similar to this on user profiles.  If you find an active bounty, click on the user who created it, and navigate to their bounty tab you will see something like:

[image: Screenshot showing bounty worth 100 with "ends in 22 minutes" after the bounty amount but before the title]

Today, that is rendered with a special view only used in user profiles.  In the distant past, it was rendered with the same UI used on question lists, by passing `{ "shwowBountyDuration", true }` in the view data dictionary. (Just sharing because the name amuses me.)  The question would render the text only if set.

Nowadays, the question list question view aren't used in user profiles and is never called with view data dictionary, so I removed the references and tried but failed to update the logic as if the variables weren't there.

Comment: This old [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186057/show-when-the-bounty-is-ending-in-the-featured-list?noredirect=1&lq=1)  might be of relevance.