# Display bounty expire time in the bounty tab

Tags: feature-request, design, bounties

**When I go to the question details page it shows the expire time form (picture one)... I am requesting it should also show in the bounty tab like (picture two).**

*I think it will be helpful for question readers...*

**Picture One**

[image]

**Picture Two**

[image]

Comment: The expiration date could also be shown when you hover over the bounty symbol.

Comment: Out of interest, why'd you redact info which is available for public anyways?

Comment: @MJV Hovering is inconvenient and doesn't quite work on smartphones. In fact this morning I was awarded a bounty on MSE and I still don't know who gave it to me because hovering on my smartphone did nothing. Oh funny, it was **noor** (the author of this question) that gave me the bounty. Thanks noor !!!

Comment: @user1271772 I agree, it is quite inconvenient, but I believe that the location where noor suggested is also inconvenient. If you placed a large amount of tags on your question, there would be no space for the bounty expiration date at that spot.

Comment: Technically noor placed it below where the tags would go.

Comment: This has already been requested: [Show when the bounty is ending in the Featured list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186057/show-when-the-bounty-is-ending-in-the-featured-list). Note that at the time, the "Bountied" tab was called the "Featured" tab. I might add that this was [mistakenly implemented due to a bug in August 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332036/remove-the-end-time-of-bounties-from-question-titles), but was removed upon request.

Comment: @Sonic the Curiouser Hedgehog _Question 1:_  7 years ago bounty tab was not exist. It’s was featured tab. I don’t know the purpose of featured tab  also he  said that we see the active Bounties on a ***certain*** tag (in this case, Python). This request was for hove effect (from the picture & question - we put the cursor box) like MJV's comment & read also user1271772 comment  _Question 2 :_ XtremeBaumer request for Remove the end time of bounties from question titles.. 
Think if today I do not need something I will leave it if tomorrow it is require I will gather

Comment: Reopening because this Feature Request is different, and a better implementation, than the other - exact details of where / how to position **visible** information is implementation specific; the ability (practicality) doesn't concern itself with the duplicity.

Comment: Hehh, anybody can recognize @Glorfindel on the upper icon in the spot :-)

Comment: The Featured tab at the time was the *exact* same as the "Bountied" tab today, just a different name, as per [this announcement from an employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332054/the-featured-tab-is-now-bountied).

Comment: @Sonic the Curiouser Hedgehog  _When we put the cursor on the blue bounty box in the list we did not see anything_ also this thing was for _cusrsor_ that means _tooltips_ .. i did not request for tooltips also read @ MJV and  @  user1271772 comment to better understand.. also it was more than 7 years ago.....

Comment: Should be changed to end -> ends

Comment: The bounties are ordered by expiration date. The expiration time could go in the existing blue banner (Picture One), which would be a less disruptive coding change (being made to something that is already bounty specific, and not to the general question template). I think it would work better with small mobile screens, as there is already a lot of info to show in the question listing.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica It's a trap! (Are you sure that is Glorfindel?)

Comment: @wimi While it would be possible to use his avatar, or a very similar one, it would be impossible to reproduce also his activity intensity, while remaining below the radar. And the probability that someone appears in a meta site screenshot, roughly correlates with his general activity intensity. I think the probability that he is not Glorfindel is below 1%. :-)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica hmm looking closely at the image, the username seems to contain the string "nfe" and end in "n". Glorfindel also did not seem to be there in the year 2009... Or are we talking about a different image...?

Comment: @wimi Actually, MSE was created by a split from the old MSO (which worked as a main site, not as a meta), this resulted various unexpected things (like posts created before about 2014 were created yet on the MSO). But you are right, mea culpa. The [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6493/259412) can be found by a simple Google/SEDE/ElasticSearch query. The OP is [tvanfosson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/12950/tvanfosson), and not Glorfindel.

Comment: @peterh [close, but not Glorfindel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75KnA.jpg)

Comment: I guess the Bounty tab is shown differently on Noor's device than on mine. On my cellphone, with the appropriate modification, it [would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmHLX.png). The difference between my example being the lack of an avatar and the additional tags; there's plenty of room for the information to be visibly presented. In the Benefactor's Profile [the bounty is shown before the question title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj1cf.jpg) - that isn't *better* but it shows that there is room available.

Comment: my intention was expire time will show left side of profile picture .. that was it. actually I did not focus my picture . it's all about padding and margin issue for  devices (responsive) ,
[image  form my laptop with 5 tags](https://i.imgur.com/0Vyg0cj.png)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Would you please read [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358008/display-bounty-expire-time-in-the-bounty-tab?noredirect=1#comment1198596_358008) just before yours :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating About your other edit (sorry I can not ping you there): as far I know, yes the company requires to get the scanned, legally valid personal identification documents of the elected mods, and yes this is what the string "called up after the election to meet additional demand" means on some election pages. While this requirement does not fulfill the literal meaning of the "Not a Robot" badge, imho it does fulfill its spirit. Things about the mods are typically not very well advertised, but I could search for some source if you wish to. Possibly I know it badly.